# Can I define custom enum-type to be used in Ghidra as a data type?

Tags: windows, binary-analysis, decompilation, static-analysis, ghidra

I'm trying to learn [Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/). Say, if it generated the following code for loading functions from an array of function names from `gpfnCommCtrlAPI`:

[image]

I was able to retype `gpfnCommCtrlAPI` into `char*[14]` which made it quite readable:

[image]

But then is it possible to retype `g_pfnsUxCtrl`, a pointer to an array of function pointers, (possibly with a custom `enum`) to make it a little bit more readable? Here's an example of how it looks now in case of `g_pfnsUxCtrl[7]`:

[image]

PS. To understand what index `7` refers to in that case I need to go back to the `gpfnCommCtrlAPI` array, which may not be immediately available where `g_pfnsUxCtrl[7]` is used.

PS2. In that case case, I manually renamed `p_comctl32_HandleScrollCmd` variable to make it more readable.

Comment: Which executable file did you analyse?

Comment: @Biswapriyo: `comctrl32.dll` x86 build from Win10.

Comment: that sounds like you want a typedef if you want X to mean g_pfnsUxCtrl[7] unless your want to use the enum to replace the 7

Answer (score 3):

you are able to add your own enum type inside `Data Type Manager`. (Keep in mind to select correct size).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then you should be able to change the type to your newly created enum and everything should be nicely resolved.

Comment: yeah, that's how you define a generic `enum`. But how would you apply it to the particular example I showed above?

Comment: if that proc list is relatively short with const count and you really would like custom names instead of integers, then you can create a custom type with lots of integers of different names. Then you'll have a single object with couple of variables and each of those will have a custom name.
And if those addresses are constant which is kinda stupid but you can look where you land with that, you can try to set `p_comct132_HandleScrollCmd` to enumType and `g_pfnsUxCtrl` to pointer to enumType.
Both solutions are silly, in your case I'd just memorize those integers